# geom_ribbon: Fill area between lines - spurious lines connecting groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-ribbon

I'm trying to build a plot with two lines and fill the area between with `geom_ribbon`. I've managed to select a fill color (red/blue) depending on the sign of the difference between two lines. First I create two new columns in the dataset for `ymax, ymin`. It seems to work but some spurious lines appear joining red areas.

Is `geom_ribbon` appropriate to fill the areas? Is there any problem in the plot code?

This is the code used to create the plot

```
datos.2022 <- datos.2022 %>% mutate(y1 = SSTm-273.15, y2 = SST.mean.day-273.15)

datos.2022 %>% ggplot(aes(x=fecha)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=SSTm-273.15), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=SST.mean.day - 273.15), color = "black") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=y1, ymin = y2, fill = as.factor(sign)), alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(guide = "none", values=c("blue","red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10,30)) +
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0), breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b" ) + 
  theme_hc() + 
  labs(x="",y ="SST",title = "Temperature (2022)") + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=20,family = "Arial"))
```

And this is the output

[image]

Example data for the plot available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkk8w7py2ynuy1t/temperature.dat?dl=0

Comment: This happens because even the separate red bits are considered one group that should be connected. There is the [{ggbraid}](https://nsgrantham.github.io/ggbraid/) package or [`ggh4x::stat_difference()`](https://teunbrand.github.io/ggh4x/articles/Statistics.html#difference) that work specifically for such cases. (Disclaimer: I wrote ggh4x)

Comment: Fantastic package, just a problem. ggbraid is not available for my R version
R version 4.2.2 Patched (2022-11-10 r83330) running under: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. Could not install in my RStudio.

Comment: I think ggbraid might be underway to CRAN, but you can install from github as well `remotes::install_github("nsgrantham/ggbraid")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you made two different series to plot as ribbons - one for the positive values where there is no distance between `ymin` and `ymax` for the places where the difference is negative.  And one for the negative values that works in a similar way.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

datos.2022 <- datos.2022 %>% 
  mutate(y1 = SSTm-273.15, 
         y2 = SST.mean.day-273.15) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(high_pos = max(SST.mean.day - 273.15, y1), 
         low_neg = min(SSTm-273.15, y2))


datos.2022 %>% ggplot(aes(x=fecha)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=SSTm-273.15), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=SST.mean.day - 273.15), color = "black") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=high_pos, ymin = SST.mean.day - 273.15, fill = "b"), alpha = 0.6, col="transparent", show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = SST.mean.day - 273.15, ymin = low_neg, fill = "a"), alpha = 0.6, col="transparent", show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(guide = "none", values=c("blue","red")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(10,30)) +
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0), breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b" ) + 
  #theme_hc() + 
  labs(x="",y ="SST",title = "Temperature (2022)") + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=20,family = "Arial"))
```

[image]

Comment: That's a nice workaround that works exactly the way I want. Now the plot is OK but it does not look "nice" to use two different ribbons. Thanks.